# How to make HML Email Template have dynamic Base URL

Tags: email, email-template, customsetting, custom-metadata, hml

We have an HML email template using the {{{}}} syntax to provide a link to a record.  Unfortunately, this syntax hard codes the base URL within the Email Template XML.  For example:

```
<a href="https://mydomain--dev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/{{{OpportunityId__c}}}/view">{{{Opportunity__c}}}</a>
```

Note the "mydomain--dev" at the beginning which is different for each Salesforce tier.  When we deploy this email template to another Salesforce tier, the base URL does not get automatically updated.  If we want to have the correct URL in each tier, this means we need to manually change the email template after each deploy, as well as apply fixes to each email template after a sandbox refresh.

Is there any way to reference a Custom Setting within an HML Email Template, so that the base URL is always correct?

HML syntax does not appear to support references to Custom Settings which is how we maintain tier-specific base URL's in Classic Email Templates.

Comment: So this is a Lightning Email Template rather than a Classic Email Template based on your reference to HML (Handlebars Merge Language), is that right?

Comment: @BrentBowers - Correct

Comment: You could use a formula field on the Opportunity that calculates this using the $API context variable

Comment: @cropredy - I believe that would work, but it just feels so wrong.  A formula field on every record of every object that has a Lightning Email Template that each contains the same value within that tier?  That seems so inefficient.

Comment: using an IDE one could create these formula fields rather quickly; I use VF email templates  with a VF component to deal with this at the moment; but perhaps others have a better solution

Comment: It's not the lift to create the formula fields that bothers me.  I can create fields quickly enough.  What bothers me is the inefficiency of the approach.  This is one value that won't change anywhere in the tier.  It should just be stored once, not defined on every record.

Comment: The comments in the relevant [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZDHUA3/add-record-detail-link-merge-field-in-lightning-email-template-like-classic) claim that the `<Object>.Link` merge field syntax that works in Classic also works in Lightning. Lightning template can be either SML or HML, so it's possible some commenters are still on SML flavor. Worth a try.